# Mouse randomly moves and clicks everywhere

Tags: elementary-project

I have a weird bug where my cursor keeps clicking and moving by itself randomly on the screen. This started happening a couple weeks ago, it does not happen on my secondary boot, so it's not a hardware issue.

Its hard to write this, because mouse keeps losing focus of the input.
My trackpad sometimes stop working either, don't know if its related.

It's really annoying, I'm almost installing another OS. Any ideas how to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was disabling the touchpad

First, find the touchpad ID with the command:
`xinput`

In my case it was "12", then disable it with:

`xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0`

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a laptop? Go into settings, mouse and touchpad and uncheck tap to click and it should stop exhibiting that behavior.

Comment: did not help =(